# How do I format this table in latex?

Tags: tables

I have this table from Stata: [image]

**EDIT:** After taking Mico's suggestion I was able to create the table with the following codes:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:1}  
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l|
         d{2.7} d{1.7} d{2.7} d{2.7} | 
         >{$}r<{$} @{${}={}$} d{4.0} @{}} % 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Variable\Bstrut} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Std.~Dev.} & \mc{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Max} & \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{Observ.}\\
\hline
\textit{lwage}\Tstrut & overall  & 1.649147  & .5326094 & -3.579079 & 4.05186 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3907468 & .3333435 & 3.174173 & n & 545\\
  & within & & .3622636 & -2.467201 & 3.204687 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
\textit{educ} & overall & 11.76697 & 1.746181 & 3 & 16 & N & 4360\\
 & between & &  1.747585 & 3 & 16    & n & 545\\
  & within & & 0 & 11.76697 & 11.76697 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  \textit{black} & overall & .1155963  & .3197769 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .320034  & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
  & within & & 0 & .1155963 & .1155963 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  \textit{hisp} & overall & .1559633 & .3628622 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3631539 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
  & within & & 0 & .1559633 & .1559633 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  \textit{exper} & overall & 6.514679 &  2.825873 & 0 & 18 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & 1.654918 & 3.5 & 14.5 & n & 545\\
  & within & & 2.291551 & 3.014679 & 10.01468 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  $exper^{2}$ & overall & 50.42477 & 40.78199 & 0 & 324 & N & 4360\\
 & between & &  26.35134 & 17.5 & 215.5  & n & 545\\
  & within & & 31.1431 & -44.07523 & 158.9248 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  \textit{married} & overall & .4389908 & .4963208 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3766116 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
  & within & & .3236137 & -.4360092 & 1.313991 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
  \textit{union} & overall & .2440367 & .4295639 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3294467 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
  & within & & .2759787 & -.6309633 & 1.119037 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, the problem now is that they're not aligned properly like the original table. How do I do that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not an exact duplicate, as I am doing the table in latex by hand.

Comment: the old q has gone so I deleted my comment:-)

Comment: By "original table", do you mean the one printed by Stata, with a monospaced font and simple dashes in lieu of typographically appropriate "minus" symbols?

Comment: @Mico Yes, by 'original' I mean the Stata table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the `dcolumn` package to align the numeric data on the decimal marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,caption}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

%% define a few struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:summ_stats}  
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l|
         d{2.7} d{1.7} d{2.7} d{2.7} | 
         >{$}r<{$} @{${}={}$} d{4.0} @{}} % 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Variable\Bstrut} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Std.~Dev.} & \mc{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Max} & \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{Observ.}\\
\hline
lwage\Tstrut & overall  & 1.649147  & .5326094 & -3.579079 & 4.05186 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3907468 & .3333435 & 3.174173 & n & 545\\
  & within & & .3622636 & -2.467201 & 3.204687 & T & 8\\[1ex] % extra vertical whitespace
educ & overall & 11.76697 & 1.746181 & 3 & 16 & N & 4360\\
etc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Addendum to address the OP's follow-up request: To make the table look (almost) like it was printed by Stata, (i) use `r` instead of `d` column types for the numeric columns, and (ii) switch to a monospaced font, e.g. by modifying the macro `\familydefault`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

%% define some typographic struts
%% (from code by Claudio Beccari in TeX and TUG News, Vol. 2, 1993)
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.9ex}}       % "top" strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1.2ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % "bottom" strut

\begin{document}
\begingroup  % localize the redefinition of \familydefault
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}\selectfont
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Summary Statistics} \label{tab:1}  
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4.5pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{} l l | rrrr | rr @{}} % 
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l|}{Variable\Bstrut} & Mean & Std.Dev. & Min & Max & \multicolumn{2}{r@{}}{Observ.}\\
\hline
lwage\Tstrut & overall  & 1.649147  & .5326094 & -3.579079 & 4.05186 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3907468 & .3333435 & 3.174173 & n & 545\\
 & within & & .3622636 & -2.467201 & 3.204687 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
educ & overall & 11.76697 & 1.746181 & 3 & 16 & N & 4360\\
 & between & &  1.747585 & 3 & 16    & n & 545\\
 & within & & 0 & 11.76697 & 11.76697 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
black & overall & .1155963  & .3197769 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .320034  & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
 & within & & 0 & .1155963 & .1155963 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
hisp & overall & .1559633 & .3628622 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3631539 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
 & within & & 0 & .1559633 & .1559633 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
exper & overall & 6.514679 &  2.825873 & 0 & 18 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & 1.654918 & 3.5 & 14.5 & n & 545\\
 & within & & 2.291551 & 3.014679 & 10.01468 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
expersq & overall & 50.42477 & 40.78199 & 0 & 324 & N & 4360\\
 & between & &  26.35134 & 17.5 & 215.5  & n & 545\\
 & within & & 31.1431 & -44.07523 & 158.9248 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
married & overall & .4389908 & .4963208 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3766116 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
 & within & & .3236137 & -.4360092 & 1.313991 & T & 8\\[1ex] 
union & overall & .2440367 & .4295639 & 0 & 1 & N & 4360\\
 & between & & .3294467 & 0 & 1 & n & 545\\
 & within & & .2759787 & -.6309633 & 1.119037 & T & 8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```